# What visa or documents are required for a visit to France as a Trinidadian?

Tags: visas, schengen, t-and-t-citizens

I am a resident of Trinidad and Tobago visiting UK and want to visit Paris via Eurostar. What type of visa, if any, do I need?

Comment: `&` is not allowed in tag names apparently. Mods, please make [tag:trinidanian-citizens] and [tag:tobagonian-citizens] synonyms of [tag:t-and-t-citizens]

Answer (score 2):

As a citizen of Trinidad-and-Tobago, you do not need a visa for a short stay in the Schengen area, including France. You will of course need a passport and might be asked to justify the purpose of your trip, show you have sufficient means to cover its costs (e.g. a credit card) and return to the UK or otherwise leave the area.

If you are a resident but not a citizen in Trinidad-and-Tobago, then the rules depend on your citizenship, being a resident there makes no difference.